# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CaseSummary, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near 'end'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create an input parameter procedure
but i'm having error in it

```
  create procedure CaseSummary (@client_id int='')
as
begin
if exists(select Client_ID from [Client] where Client_ID= @client_id)
begin
SELECT CaseRegister.Client_ID,CaseRegister.Case_ID,  CaseAssign.Lawyer_ID ,  Document.Doc_ID, CaseToCourt.Court_ID, CaseToJudge.J_ID,
 CaseDetail.Result, Clauses.Clause_ID, SubClauses.SC_ID
FROM((((((((( CaseAssign
INNER JOIN Lawyer ON CaseAssign.Lawyer_ID = Lawyer.Lawyer_ID)
Inner Join CaseRegister ON CaseAssign.CR_ID = CaseRegister.CR_ID)
Inner Join Client ON Client.Client_ID = CaseRegister.Client_ID)
Inner Join Document On Document.Client_ID= Client.Client_ID)
Inner JOIn CaseToCourt On  CaseToCourt.CR_ID= CaseRegister.CR_ID ) 
Inner Join CaseToJudge On CaseToJudge.CR_ID = CaseRegister.CR_ID )
Inner Join CaseDetail on CaseDetail.CJ_ID = CaseToJudge.CJ_ID )
Inner join Clauses on Clauses.CD_ID = CaseDetail.CD_ID)
Inner Join SubClauses on SubClauses.Clause_ID = Clauses.Clause_ID);
END
```

error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CaseSummary, Line 18
>   Incorrect syntax near 'end'.

Comment: 1) Joins don't have to be encased in parentheses. I'm not going to attempt to work out whether *those* are balanced here and 2) I count two `begin`s and only one `end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
create procedure CaseSummary (@client_id int='')
as

if exists(select Client_ID from [Client] where Client_ID= @client_id)
begin
SELECT CaseRegister.Client_ID,CaseRegister.Case_ID,  CaseAssign.Lawyer_ID ,  Document.Doc_ID, CaseToCourt.Court_ID, CaseToJudge.J_ID,
 CaseDetail.Result, Clauses.Clause_ID, SubClauses.SC_ID
FROM CaseAssign
INNER JOIN Lawyer ON CaseAssign.Lawyer_ID = Lawyer.Lawyer_ID
Inner Join CaseRegister ON CaseAssign.CR_ID = CaseRegister.CR_ID
Inner Join Client ON Client.Client_ID = CaseRegister.Client_ID
Inner Join Document On Document.Client_ID= Client.Client_ID
Inner JOIn CaseToCourt On  CaseToCourt.CR_ID= CaseRegister.CR_ID  
Inner Join CaseToJudge On CaseToJudge.CR_ID = CaseRegister.CR_ID 
Inner Join CaseDetail on CaseDetail.CJ_ID = CaseToJudge.CJ_ID 
Inner join Clauses on Clauses.CD_ID = CaseDetail.CD_ID
Inner Join SubClauses on SubClauses.Clause_ID = Clauses.Clause_ID
END
```

The 'begin' at the start either needs an 'end' at the end OR just don't specify it

Comment: I removed the first begin and "Command(s) completed successfully."

Comment: @syedjunaid great. Mark as the answer when you can